# Using bold font to display a macro in LaTeX

Tags: moderncv, bold

I need to type a letter, and according to German standards, there must be a subject line in bold font.

I'm using the `moderncv` documentclass, with the fancy option, and I've defined the command subject like this:

```
\newcommand*{\subject}[1]{\def\@subject{#1}}
```

in the `moderncv.cls` file.

To display it bold I've edited the command `\makelettertitle` from the file `moderncvheadv.sty`, using this line:

```
\textbf{\@subject}
```

But it gives the same output as`\@subject`.

How can I tell LaTeX to print the subject in bold font ?

Here's my document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}        
\moderncvstyle{fancy}                                   
\moderncvcolor{red}                               

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}




\name{First}{Last}
\title{Lebenslauf}                               
\address{street}{City}{}

\recipient{Herr Mister}{Firma GmbH}
\date{\today}
\opening{Sehr geehrter Herr Mister,}
\subject{Bewerbung für eine Stelle.}
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}

\begin{document}

\makelettertitle
Blablabla, nice letter...
\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Apparently, it's a problem concerning the `roman` font. It works perfectly with the `sans` font. I don't need help to finish my letter anymore, however, I'll try to find out where the problem is and I'll update it here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should give us more information.

Comment: I am a German: Out of curiosity: Which German standard?

Comment: I'll add an example as soon as I can

It's the DIN 5008. It's not required to make it bold, but recommended.

Comment: I will look later on...

Comment: Now, I am no `moderncv` expert, but where does `\subject` come in? Where is `\@subject` used at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to print `\@subject` it's necessary to wrap a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair around `\textbf{\@subject}`. However I suggest to use wrapper command if this has to be done more than once!

```
\documentclass{article}



\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\subject}[1]{\def\@subject{#1}}
\newcommand{\boldsubject}{\textbf{\@subject}}
\makeatother

\subject{First}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
Bold: \textbf{\@subject}

\@subject
\makeatother


Bold again: \boldsubject


\end{document}
```

Comment: Since it was a problem with the font I was using, this answer works. Thanks !